# Qt Creator not able to include C++ 11 headers

Tags: c++11, qt-creator

I have qmake project with some headers and some .c files, in some of the header files I'm using C++11 headers, I have added CONFIG += c++11 option in .pro file, but the problem is IDE is not able to include C++ 11 specific headers say vector (for syntax highlighting), but the code builds. The  issue resolves at the moment if I add a C++ class with .cpp file. But I dont want to do that.

Qt Creator version 4.5.1

Qt 5.6

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

Comment: You have C++ code in `.c` files?

Comment: @Mat Yes, I have few .h files and few .c files

Comment: Well that's going to confuse a lot of tools. Use `.cpp`, `.cxx` or `.cc` extensions for C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GCC as your compiler, it only recognises files with the following extensions as C++ source files: `.C (note the uppercase), .cc, .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp, .cxx`. I'm not aware of a compiler that recognises `.c` as a C++ source file.

Rename your source files' extensions to one of the above so that QtCreator is not confused.